# How to access child component from parent component in Ember

Tags: ember.js, web-applications, frontend, ember-octane

The concept is fairly simple.

Assume I have a child component with its own separate js and hbs.
Child-component.hbs =>

```
<Button options = {{listOptions}} selected={{selectedOption}}
> Submit <Button
```

Child-component.js

```
listOptions =[{id: 124, name: 'Mywork'}
selected => performing an action after getting the value from hbs selection.
```

Now I'm importing this into another component `Main-component.hbs` like this

```
<ChildComponent />
```

This is rendering as expected with options and all, but based on the `selectedOption` I want to do something in my main component. Handling the action in the Main-component is not an option for me as its not what I was told to do. Is it possible to access `selectedOption` from the main-component? Kindly help.

Please note that I want to achieve this in Octane version.

Comment: Hi @Kumar! To answer this question we'd need a bit more context, especially regarding _I want to do something in my main component_. The answer really depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sure, in main-component.hbs, I have a nav-footer which contacts 2 buttons. One ```Cancel``` and ```Next```. 

If the child-component's value ```selectedOption``` is empty, I have to disable the ```Next``` button. 
To put it simply, I want to write 

```<Button @disabled={{ not selectedOption}} onclick={{action "myAction"}}>Next</Button
```

@AndreyStukalin

Answer (score 2):

the only way to do this is to specifically pass a reference from the parent to the child, and have the child invoke some function on the parent (because, in rendering, data only flows down by default ("data down, actions/functions up"))

Example:

```
class Parent {
  foo(child) {
    // do something with the child
  }
}
<Child @foo={{this.foo}} />

// ------------------

class Child { }
{{ (@foo this) }}
```

Note that this is an "effect", and effects are generally a code-smell (derived data should be used whenever possible)